# Recording voice calls in android

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder, phone-call, voice-recording

I want to make an app that records incoming and outgoing calls. I am using the media recorder to do so and also I am using service/broadcastreceiver to detect phone state change. I have set the audio source as Audiosource.VOICE_CALLS.I am able to record voices at my end but not from the other end. The same happens when the audio source is set as Audiosource.MIC.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: where are you running your app?On emulater or device(specify it)

Comment: on device...Samsung galaxy S and galaxy note N7000

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access the incall audio stream in Android using the public SDK. Call audio is not exposed to apps, and you can only do this if you modify Android at a source level, and then build and install a new image from the customized source to your device.

Comment: but there are apps that record calls...do they also modify android at source level?

Comment: @MridulaTripathi They probably exploit bugs that only exist on some devices, or play the call over the loudspeaker and record it through the mike. Do you have a link to such apps?

Comment: i tried giving the mic option too but the other side voice could not be recorded.
Here is such an app and i have tested it on Samsung galaxy Note N7000 too...
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hcHBzdGFyLmNhbGxyZWNvcmRlciJd

Comment: @RaghavSood check cube call recorder. It is using voice call(software) for Audio input and recording call nicely